# Error when trying to click in a view created programmatically swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I created a view programmatically, like a popup coming from the top with some text and images in there!

```
alert = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width , height: 0))
alert?.frame.origin.y = (textLable?.frame.height)!
alert?.frame.size.height = (textLable?.frame.height)!
alert?.backgroundColor = self.arrayOptions.colorBackground
```

and then I'm trying to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to that view like this inside a setup func that is called in the init.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.teste))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
alert?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

im adding that view like this in a UitableViewController:

```
self.popView = PopupView(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0 , width:self.view.frame.width, height: 0), with: PopUpOptions.error, originY: 0,description:"blablabla")
self.view.addSubview(self.popView!)
```

But when I tap on the view nothing happens, but when I tap repeatedly over and over this error occurs:

> <_UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer: 0x174186f50>: Gesture: Failed
>   to receive system gesture state notification before next touch

But I cant seem to find an answer for this, could anyone help me pls!
Thank you!

here is the GitHub link https://github.com/Coimbraa/AlertsPopup_framework for my framework

Comment: Are you creating `alert` and `tap` and then `alert?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` all in a `PopupView` function? All inside a cell subclass? And `self.teste` is *also* a func inside that class? And `self.view.addSubview(self.popView!)` is ***also*** inside that class? It might help if you simply post the full class so we can see when/where you are running these bits of code...

Comment: ill leave here the gitHub link to my project https://github.com/Coimbraa/AlertsPopup_framework im trying to build a framework and in other classes from the main project im implementing that framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a look at your GitHub repo - Couple notes...

I see a lot of "**!"** in your code. Each one of those is a potential crash. For example, I had to make a number of edits just to get it to run at all (I don't have the image assets the code is expecting).

In `PopUpView.swift` change the `init()` func to this (just added the `clipsToBounds` line):

```
override public init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Now, when you call `popView?.toggleStatus()` you probably won't see ***anything***.

Your PopupView "container" has a height of Zero. Without clipping its contents, you **see** the content, but you can't interact with it.

I changed your animation block in `toggleStatus()` to this:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        if let sz = self.alert?.frame.size {
            self.frame.size.height = sz.height
        }
        self.alert?.frame.origin.y =  (self.startY)! + (self.status ? 0 : -((self.textLable?.frame.height)! + self.startY))
    }) { (finished:Bool) in
    // ...
```

and I could now tap into and edit the TextView, and tap elsewhere and get `print("pressed")` output to the debug console.

I did not dig further, so I don't know if/where you need to put additional code to reset the frame-height back to Zero (or maybe it gets hidden or removed, whatever).

Comment: Yeah you are right! i know that about the images im still working on it so i didnt put them in the assets file yet sorry about that, and the mess with my code still working on it xd and yeah it seems to be working now! thanks so much for your time reviewing my code and for your helpful tips! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Set this property to `true` for those views you want to tap on (where you add the tap gesture recognizer).

Comment: didnt work :( I might be doing something wrong that i still have not find

Answer (score 0):

You are adding that Custom Alert View in Table View Controller.

First try what Tung Fam has suggested, if it doesn't work then,

Trying adding it on window like:

```
self.view.window.addSubview(self.popView!)
```

Also set the frame of the window to the popupView.

Comment: not working, it still wont click and appear the same error

Answer (score 0):

As I'm seeing you are setting target for TapGesture as self in

`let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.teste))`

Here `self` is object of UIView (your alert view).

So according to this line your tapGesture listener must be implemented in `alert?` class. And you need to use custom protocol or custom delegate to get the action of tapGesture in other classes.